# Google Cloud Speech text language

Tags: google-cloud-speech

Is the returned text of the audio file always in English? I know there is a way to configure the language of the audio file, but is there a way to configure the language of the output text? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to pass Language code to the API ([1](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionConfig)) or to the client library of your choice. For example, take a look at how RecognitionConfig object is constructed in Java ([2](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java))

Comment: Language Code: "Required The language of the supplied audio as a BCP-47 language tag. Example: "en-US". See Language Support for a list of the currently supported language codes."
This is to let Google know the language of the Audio, not the language of the transcribed text.